# How to get Image displayed in DBWPRichText component which inturn connected to Memotype Field?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, rtf, tadodataset

I am working with Client server architecture in Delphi with SQL server 2014 as the database.

I have a database fieldname "Document" that is of type "Text" which contains rtf data which contains an image data. I am using ado dataset which gets the field as "Memo". This ado dataset is in turn connected to a client dataset and connects to a DBWPRichText control. The "Document" field data that is fetched is getting truncated which results in loss of image data being displayed in DBWPRichText.

I tried adding the field in dataset as Blob and could get the Image displayed in the DBWPRichText control. Alas! while saving the data via dataset post method getting error message ***"Text is incompatible with image"***.
I think this could be because of field being changed to BLOB manually by me to display the Image where **db field is of the type "Text"** .

*Tried with WPRichText which works fine where I am loading data from fieldname "Document" however while loading into control I am converting string to stream and while saving converting the WPRichText control data from stream to string.*

In my case I have to use DBWPRichText control connected to a database as there are few mail merge fields involved and dont want to loose those.
By the way cannot change the field type as it is used in almost many places and dont want to break anything.

If any one can guide a way through to go achieve with DBWPRichText without changing the db field type would be really appreciated.

Thanks